# I would like to convert PDF to excel

Tags: excel, tcpdf

Am very new to programming,I have some experience in fortran(Am from a physics background) I would like to write a code to extract specific information from PDF files. Can anyone guide me on how to get started?? Sure I can use the tons of online applications available, but i like to write the code myself.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you want to write the code yourself! What have you already tried? You need to try something first in order for us to help you. As you are new and don't know much about us, please read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I understand, Will come back when I get stuck, Which will be pretty soon! Thank You:)

Answer (score 0):

PDF doesn't conserve table format, it just retains the original position of the text. However, https://scraperwiki.com/ has helped me before. They also have a section where you can write your own code, I haven't used that but it's probably a good place to start.

I also found this [website](http://schoolofdata.org/2013/06/18/get-started-with-scraping-extracting-simple-tables-from-pdf-documents/), it looks like it explains what you want (it uses scraperwiki).